# How to read data from Api using getx Obx

Tags: flutter, api, rest, dart, flutter-getx

lateinitialization error shows on the first loading of screen.datas are only getting after i hot reload my app.please help me to solve this issue.
It is an api to get details of a single actor. I want it to done Using Getx Obx.

Thanks in advance.

This is the data of API i need to read in to my app

```
{
  "adult": false,
  "also_known_as": [
    " Edward Harrison ",
    "Ed Norton",
    "爱德华·诺顿",
    "เอ็ดเวิร์ด นอร์ตัน",
    "Эдвард Нортон",
    "エドワード・ノートン",
    "إدوارد نورتون",
    "에드워드 노튼",
    "Έντουαρντ Νόρτον",
    "Edward Harrison Norton",
    "אדוארד נורטון",
    "ادوارد نورتون"
  ],
  "biography": "Edward Harrison Norton (born August 18, 1969) is an American actor and filmmaker. He has received numerous awards and nominations, including a Golden Globe Award and three Academy Award nominations.\n\nBorn in Boston, Massachusetts and raised in Columbia, Maryland, Norton was drawn to theatrical productions at local venues as a child. After graduating from Yale College in 1991, he worked for a few months in Japan before moving to New York City to pursue an acting career. He gained immediate recognition and critical acclaim for his debut in Primal Fear (1996), which earned him a Golden Globe for Best Supporting Actor and an Academy Award nomination in the same category. His role as a reformed neo-Nazi in American History X (1998) earned him an Academy Award nomination for Best Actor. He also starred in the film Fight Club (1999), which garnered a cult following.\n\nNorton emerged as a filmmaker in the 2000s. He established the production company Class 5 Films in 2003, and was director or producer of the films Keeping the Faith (2000), Down in the Valley (2005), and The Painted Veil (2006). He continued to receive critical acclaim for his acting roles in films such as The Score (2001), 25th Hour (2002), The Illusionist (2006), Moonrise Kingdom (2012), and The Grand Budapest Hotel (2014). His biggest commercial successes have been Red Dragon (2002), Kingdom of Heaven (2005), The Incredible Hulk (2008), and The Bourne Legacy (2012). For his role in the black comedy Birdman (2014), Norton earned another Academy Award nomination for Best Supporting Actor.",
  "birthday": "1969-08-18",
  "deathday": null,
  "gender": 2,
  "homepage": null,
  "id": 819,
  "imdb_id": "nm0001570",
  "known_for_department": "Acting",
  "name": "Edward Norton",
  "place_of_birth": "Boston, Massachusetts, USA",
  "popularity": 11.598,
  "profile_path": "/5XBzD5WuTyVQZeS4VI25z2moMeY.jpg"
}
```

here is my model which i generated from quicktype ,

```
  import 'dart:convert';

ActorModel actorModelFromJson(String str) => ActorModel.fromJson(json.decode(str));

String actorModelToJson(ActorModel data) => json.encode(data.toJson());

class ActorModel {
    ActorModel({
        this.adult,
        this.alsoKnownAs,
        this.biography,
        this.birthday,
        this.deathday,
        this.gender,
        this.homepage,
        this.id,
        this.imdbId,
        this.knownForDepartment,
        this.name,
        this.placeOfBirth,
        this.popularity,
        this.profilePath,
    });

    bool? adult;
    List<String>? alsoKnownAs;
    String? biography;
    DateTime? birthday;
    dynamic deathday;
    int? gender;
    dynamic? homepage;
    int? id;
    String? imdbId;
    String? knownForDepartment;
    String? name;
    String? placeOfBirth;
    double? popularity;
    String? profilePath;

    factory ActorModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => ActorModel(
        adult: json["adult"],
        alsoKnownAs: List<String>.from(json["also_known_as"].map((x) => x)),
        biography: json["biography"],
        birthday: DateTime.parse(json["birthday"]),
        deathday: json["deathday"],
        gender: json["gender"],
        homepage: json["homepage"],
        id: json["id"],
        imdbId: json["imdb_id"],
        knownForDepartment: json["known_for_department"],
        name: json["name"],
        placeOfBirth: json["place_of_birth"],
        popularity: json["popularity"].toDouble(),
        profilePath: json["profile_path"],
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "adult": adult,
        "also_known_as": List<dynamic>.from(alsoKnownAs!.map((x) => x)),
        "biography": biography,
        "birthday": "${birthday!.year.toString().padLeft(4, '0')}-${birthday!.month.toString().padLeft(2, '0')}-${birthday!.day.toString().padLeft(2, '0')}",
        "deathday": deathday,
        "gender": gender,
        "homepage": homepage,
        "id": id,
        "imdb_id": imdbId,
        "known_for_department": knownForDepartment,
        "name": name,
        "place_of_birth": placeOfBirth,
        "popularity": popularity,
        "profile_path": profilePath,
    };
}
```

here is my Api Fetching Page code :

```
 class ActorService{
late  ActorModel actors;
  Future<ActorModel> getActorDetails()async{
     final url = 'https://api.themoviedb.org/3/person/819?api_key=++++api key++++&language=en-US';
     final response = await http.get(Uri.parse(url));
     if (response.statusCode == 200) {
       final data = jsonDecode(response.body);
         actors = ActorModel.fromJson(data);
     }
     return actors;
  }
}
```

here is my Getx controller page :

```
     class ActorController extends GetxController{
  late ActorModel actors;
   @override
  void onInit() {
    getActorInfo();
    super.onInit();
  }

  void getActorInfo()async{
    var actorInfo = await ActorService().getActorDetails();
    if (actorInfo != null) {
      actors = actorInfo;
    }
  }
}
```

this is how i reading data in my screen .

```
Text(actorController.actors.name.toString()),
```

Comment: can you include also the view of how you tried to show that data ?

Comment: using obx like this 

Text(actorController.actors.name.toString()),

Answer (score 0):

First you have to make RxVariable in GetXController class for store your data with model class.

```
1.Rx<ActorModel> actorModelDetail = ActorModel().obs;
```

After that call the api and store data in to RxVariable.

```
2.actorModelDetail.value = ActorModel(...);
```

After that used this variable in your stateless or stateful widget class and wrap this varible with Obx.

```
///Declare this in your stateless or stateful widget.
3.ActorController actorController = Get.find();

Obx(() => Text(actorController.actorModelDetail.value.name))
```